# Why synchronized shows BLOCKED state and Locks and semaphores shows WAITING state of the Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, semaphore, synchronized

When threads are waiting to access the critical section using synchronized block why the threads states show as BLOCKED and when the threads are waiting to access the critical section using Lock or semaphores threads state show as WAITING?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens according to the java documentation.

From [the javadoc for `BLOCKED`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html#BLOCKED):

> ... A thread in the blocked state is waiting for a monitor lock to enter a synchronized block/method ...

`ReentrantLock` and `Semaphore` use `LockSupport.park()` internally, and, according to [this javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html#WAITING), that corresponds to a `WAITING` thread state:

> A thread is in the waiting state due to calling one of the following methods:
>
> - Object.wait with no timeout
> - Thread.join with no timeout
> - LockSupport.park